# Open a local html file with url params through applescript

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, osx-lion, openurl

I need some help with a very simple applescript.  I need it to open a local URL on mac with a url parameter.

```
set str to "open -a 'Firefox' file:///Users/bob/Desktop/someFolder/index.html?val=28"

do shell script str
```

I can't find a way to get the webpage to open with the parameters, it always just opens the .html.

Can someone help?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use Safari, which is scriptable:

```
tell application "Safari"
    make new document with properties {URL:"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710803/open-a-local-html-file-with-url-params-through-applescript?bob=bob"}
end tell
```

The `open` command is a general-purpose function, meant to open any file with any program. It will simply look for file location and ignore the rest of the string.

Comment: To just open location without creating a new window try `tell application "Safari" to open location “http://...”`