# Open a web page with URL params from the command line, LOCALLY

Tags: macos, shell

Okay, not sure if this is even possible to do locally.  I'm using Mac OS X, and can do the following to open a remote web page with URL params:

open http://www.google.com?blah=haha

but when I try to do the same with a local file path, I get file not found errors.  Is there a way to do something like this:

open file://localhost/path/to/my/file.html?blah=heehee

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use AppleScript. `open` command is for general purpose only: it opens that file(s) with that application, nothing more. Here you can find the right way: [Open a local html file with url params through applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710803/open-a-local-html-file-with-url-params-through-applescript)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Sylter!  Final script below will open Safari with whatever is passed in

```
on run argv
tell application "Safari"
      make new document with properties {URL: item 1 of argv}
end tell
end run
```

Comment: If you don’t need to create a new window try `tell application "Safari" to open location “http://...”`

Answer (score 0):

A simpler method is running this in the command line:

```
open -u https://example.com
```